# Possible to customize position and layout of .outlineDisclosure Option for UICollectionView (list style)?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlistcell

Currently I have the following layout:
[image]

But I want to get this layout for the headers (expanded state):
[image]

So essentialy I need a custom view for the disclosure indicator because for the expanded state it should point to the bottom and for the collapsed state it should point at the top (see above picture). In addition the disclosure indicator should be on the left.

**What I have done so far**
With this code I get the first example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    enum ListItem: Hashable {
        case header(HeaderItem)
        case symbol(SFSymbolItem)
    }
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<HeaderItem, ListItem>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureCollectionView()
        setupDataSource()
        updateDate(items: HeaderItem.modelObjects)
    }

    private func configureCollectionView() {
        let layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
        let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
        
        collectionView.register(CustomListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomListCell.reuseID)
        
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = listLayout
        
        view.addSubview(collectionView)

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    private func setupDataSource() {
        let headerCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, HeaderItem> {
            (cell, indexPath, headerItem) in

            var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            config.text = headerItem.title
            cell.contentConfiguration = config
            
            let headerDisclosureOption = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header)
            cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(options: headerDisclosureOption)]
            
            //cell.accessories = [.customView(configuration: .init(customView: UIView(), placement: .trailing(displayed: .always, at: .center), isHidden: <#T##Bool?#>, reservedLayoutWidth: <#T##UICellAccessory.LayoutDimension?#>, tintColor: <#T##UIColor?#>, maintainsFixedSize: <#T##Bool?#>))]
        }

        let symbolCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, SFSymbolItem> {
            (cell, indexPath, symbolItem) in
            
            var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            config.text = symbolItem.name
            cell.contentConfiguration = config
        }
        
        dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<HeaderItem, ListItem>(collectionView: collectionView) {
            (collectionView, indexPath, listItem) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
            
            switch listItem {
            case .header(let headerItem):
                
                // Dequeue header cell
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: headerCellRegistration,
                                                                        for: indexPath,
                                                                        item: headerItem)
                return cell
                
            case .symbol(let symbolItem):
                
                // Dequeue symbol cell
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: symbolCellRegistration,
                                                                        for: indexPath,
                                                                        item: symbolItem)
                return cell
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updateDate(items: [HeaderItem]) {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<HeaderItem, ListItem>()
        snapshot.appendSections(items)
        
        for headerItem in items {
            
            //section snapshot
            var sectionSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListItem>()
            let headerListItem = ListItem.header(headerItem)
            sectionSnapshot.append([headerListItem])
            
            
            let symbolListItemArray = headerItem.symbols.map { ListItem.symbol($0) }
            sectionSnapshot.append(symbolListItemArray, to: headerListItem)
            
            dataSource.apply(sectionSnapshot, to: headerItem, animatingDifferences: false)
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
struct HeaderItem: Hashable {
    let title: String
    let symbols: [SFSymbolItem]
}

struct SFSymbolItem: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let image: UIImage
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.image = UIImage(systemName: name)!
    }
}

extension HeaderItem {
    static let modelObjects = [
        
        HeaderItem(title: "Communication", symbols: [
            SFSymbolItem(name: "mic"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "mic.fill"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "message"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "message.fill"),
        ]),
        
        HeaderItem(title: "Weather", symbols: [
            SFSymbolItem(name: "sun.min"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "sun.min.fill"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "sunset"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "sunset.fill"),
        ]),
        
        HeaderItem(title: "Objects & Tools", symbols: [
            SFSymbolItem(name: "pencil"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "pencil.circle"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "highlighter"),
            SFSymbolItem(name: "pencil.and.outline"),
        ]),
        
    ]
}
```

**Edit:**
I was able to get closer to the desired result by using `.customView(...)` as accesory type.

```
let testAction = UIAction(image: UIImage(systemName: "chevron.up"), handler: { [weak self] _ in
    //expand / collapse programmatically
})

let testBtn = UIButton(primaryAction: testAction)

let customAccessory = UICellAccessory.CustomViewConfiguration(
    customView: testBtn,
    placement: .leading(displayed: .always))

cell.accessories = [.customView(configuration: customAccessory)]
```

[image]
Is it possible to do the collapsing / expanding programmatically by clicking on the customView?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar while maintaining the chevron animation. Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't. I ended up letting the chevron change it's direction without animation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple workaround, but it will fulfill your requirement. Instead of creating a custom accessory view simply use the `.image` property of the `UIListContentConfiguration` and change it based on the state. With that, your headerCellRegistration will look something like the below:

```
let headerCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<HeaderListCell, HeaderItem> {
    (cell, indexPath, headerItem) in
    
    var config = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    config.text = headerItem.title
    cell.contentConfiguration = config
    
    //    Simply make the outlineDisclosure accessory invisible but functional.
    let headerDisclosureOption = UICellAccessory.OutlineDisclosureOptions(style: .header, tintColor: .clear)
    cell.accessories = [.outlineDisclosure(options: headerDisclosureOption)]
}

class HeaderListCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    override func updateConfiguration(using state: UICellConfigurationState) {
        super.updateConfiguration(using: state)
        
        guard var cConfig = self.contentConfiguration?.updated(for: state) as? UIListContentConfiguration else { return }
        cConfig.image = state.isExpanded ? UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down") : UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right")
        cConfig.imageProperties.reservedLayoutSize = CGSize(width: 12.0, height: 12.0)
        cConfig.imageToTextPadding = 16.0
        
        self.contentConfiguration = cConfig
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem, cheers!